# Android ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED called everytime?

Tags: android, device, boot

I am trying to write a code in Android , to create a condition during booting but my condition satisfies everytime ( during booting as well as during running of the device also). I am trying to do is , to execute the condition during the booting only.

**My Code :**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bootingtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED!=null) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is booting ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  } 
}
```

I have given manifest permission .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I want to execute this condition only during booting or device start-up but this condition satisfies every time , whenever I open the app.

Please suggest to me how I can run the condition only during the device booting or start-up.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6):

The `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is a constant, so it's values never changes, that's why you get always true when you activity starts.

What you have to do is declare a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) on the manifest and implement it, than add a [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) on your declaration to receive the broadcast.
Something like this:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
....
<receiver 
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

...

BootReceiver.java:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do what you need to execute on boot here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the class `Intent` has a string called `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` that is not null (it has a value). that is what you are checking. what you mean to do is done completely different in a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: yes i am only doing in BroadcastReceiver , but i post the different code. so then you mean to say ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED  called only during onReceive....

Comment: Yes! all you are doing in the posted code is verifying that Android's Intent class has ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED != null (it is NOT null!!!)